# $anchorScroll to asynchronously bound element id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor-scroll

Given this markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-attr-id="id-{{i}}">{{i}}</li>
```

Injecting `$anchorScroll` (so that it is instantiated), will cause the window to scroll to a bound id if it matches the hash in the url, so `/#id-4` will be scrolled to when it loads.

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4];
})
```

Unexpectedly, if the `$scope` binding is loaded asynchronously, `$anchorScroll` doesn't work automatically OR manually by calling `$anchorScroll()` at any time, even in a directive where I can verify that the id is already set. That baffles me.

**[Demo here (comment in/out the initial $scope binding).](http://jsbin.com/fobuji/3/edit)**

Here's what I came up with, but it seems like there should be a more natural way using `$anchorScroll`. In fact, it works in the demo, but very oddly is not working in my
project.

```
.directive('anchorScrollToId', function($location) {
  
  var directive = {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      if ($location.hash() === $attrs.id) {
        $element[0].scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  };
  
  return directive;
  
})
```

[**My directive demo here.**](http://jsbin.com/fobuji/4/edit)

There must be more to this issue than there seems.

### Update

On further investigation, the problem may be due to `ui-router` and it's default `autoscroll` behavior. I haven't been able to overcome this issue messing around with that.